# Finding the coefficient of $x^{r}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

Find the coefficient of $x^{r}$ in the expression -

$$(x+3)^{n-1} +(x+3)^{n-2}(x+2)+(x+3)^{n-3}(x+2)^{2}+....+(x+2)^{n-1}$$

Attempt-

I tried to write it as a binomial expansion but the binomial coefficients posed a problem

Comment: Did you notice that the expression is the sum of a geometric progression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Apply the identity $\left(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+\cdots+b^{n-1}\right)(a-b)=a^n-b^n$.